# Pivoting and merging data from a sql query

Tags: sql, merge, pivot

**This is My Query:**

```
SELECT  ad.Name, av.Value AS Attribute1, ctv.Value AS Attribute2
FROM    AttributeDefinitions AS ad WITH (nolock) 
INNER JOIN AttributeValues AS av WITH (nolock) 
ON      ad.AttributeDefinitionID = av.AttributeDefinitionID 
INNER JOIN AttributeCategories 
ON      ad.AttributeCategoryID = AttributeCategories.AttributeCategoryID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CodeTableValues AS ctv WITH (nolock) 
ON      av.CodeTableValueID = ctv.CodeTableValueID
WHERE   (AttributeCategories.Name = 'Camp') AND (av.AttributeValueGroupID = 9840)
```

**My Result Looks Like This:**

```
Name                     Attribute1      Attribute2
Childs Age:              10 
Attended Camp Before?:   Yes
Childs T-Shirt Size:     large           NULL
Allergies Description    none            NULL
Phone #                  212-555-1212    NULL
Pickup                   Mary Jordan     NULL

Name= Name of Attribute Column
Attribute1 = Data is from a free Form
Attribute2 = Data is from a Drop down Menu
```

What I would like to do is Rotate the data so that the information from column “Name” becomes the column header and I need to combine the values from attribute 1 & 2
This is what my Result Should Look Like:

```
*Childs Age  Attended Camp Before?  Childs T-Shirt Size  Allergies Description Phone#        Pickup*
10           yes                    large                none                  212-555-1212  Mary Jordan
```

Comment: If you are using SQL server 2005 or above you can use [Pivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)

Comment: What's the logic as far as which of the attributes is chosen?  Does Attribute1 always have priority over Attribute2?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle DB I am using CASE statement to convert rows into columns.

Take a look on this example:

```
select event_date
      ,sum(case when service_type = 'OCSAC_DEG'  then service_count end) ocsac_deg
      ,sum(case when service_type = 'SMS_ONL'    then service_count end) sms_onl        
      ,sum(case when service_type = 'SMS_DEG'    then service_count end) sms_deg
      ,sum(case when service_type = 'DATA_ONL'   then service_count end) data_onl        
      ,sum(case when service_type = 'DATA_DEG'   then service_count end) data_deg             
 from STATS
where to_char(event_date, 'yyyymm') = to_char(add_months(sysdate,-1), 'yyyymm')   
group by event_date
order by event_date desc
```